# Условие ввода текста - только буквы. Язык Си

Tags: c, char, циклы

Программа запрашивает ввод текста. Текст должен состоять только из букв (больших и маленьких)
Как это сделать с помощью цикла do while?
Как задать условие, что пока текст не из a-z или A-Z - повторный вввод.

Comment: Укажите в метках, какой именно язык программирования.

Comment: Мб регулярные выражения?  Что то вроде `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальный макрос для проверки буквенных символов:

```
man 3 isalpha


isalpha()
     checks  for an alphabetic character; in the standard "C" locale, it is equivalent to (isupper(c) || islower(c)).  In some locales,
 there may be additional  characters  for  which isalpha() is
 true—letters which are neither uppercase nor lower‐case.
```

Пример использования :

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char test_string[]="qw12rt34as+|kl";
    int j;

    for(j=0; j< strlen(test_string); j++) {
        if (isalpha(test_string[j]) )
            printf("Символ '%c' является алфавитным\n", test_string[j]);
        else
            printf("Символ '%c' НЕ является алфавитным\n", test_string[j]);
    }
}
```

Выдача программы:

```
Символ 'q' является алфавитным
Символ 'w' является алфавитным
Символ '1' НЕ является алфавитным
Символ '2' НЕ является алфавитным
Символ 'r' является алфавитным
Символ 't' является алфавитным
Символ '3' НЕ является алфавитным
Символ '4' НЕ является алфавитным
Символ 'a' является алфавитным
Символ 's' является алфавитным
Символ '+' НЕ является алфавитным
Символ '|' НЕ является алфавитным
Символ 'k' является алфавитным
Символ 'l' является алфавитным
```

Comment: Покажете пример, как им пользоваться в C/C++ ?

Comment: Команда man работает под линукс. Ответ больше похож на коментарий чем ответ.

Comment: По поводу man: многие мои коллеги, работающие под Windows, скачали и установили аналог man-системы для виндов и активно им пользуются. Где взяли - не буду говорить, так как не знаю...

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[256];
int ok = 1;
do {
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    ok = 1;
    if (fgets(buf,256,stdin) == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error!\n");
        ok = 0;
        break;
    }
    for(char * с = buf; *c; c++)
        if (!isalpha(*c)) { ok = 0; break; }
} while(ok == 0);
if (ok) {
    printf("Все в порядке\n");
}
```

Что-то вроде этого.